# Replacing content on click of a dynamically created button and an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have dynamically created menu buttons that when clicked fire an AJAX call to a PHP script, on success the returned data is then displayed within a specific `div` using `$("#imageFrame").append(...)`. All of the buttons in this menu are created the same way and have the same function appending data to one `div`.

The only issue I have is emptying the `div` before appending it with new content.

I have tried the `.empty()`  -  `.html('')`  - `.empty().append(<html code>)`  -`.replaceWith()`. I have put these before the AJAX post and within the success callback. The best I have achieved so far is emptying the div, it's almost as if once the empty command is run and successful the script goes no further.

**The click AJAX function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {//READY FUNC
$(".albumName").click(function(){//click
    var albumid = this.id;

    $.post("includes/viewgallery.php",{albumId:albumid},function(data)  {//json
        console.log(data);  
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
           $.each(data, function(key, val) {//iterate each data
               var albumName = val.albumName;
               var photoId = val.photoId;
               var photoName = val.photoName;
               var photoUrl = val.photoUrl;
               var thumbId = val.thumbId;
               var thumbName = val.thumbName;
               var thumbnailUrl = val.thumbnailUrl;
               var href = "http://217.199.187.191/mandingaarts.co.uk";

             $('#imageFrame').append('<a href="'+href+'' +photoUrl+ '" target="#lightbox"><img class="thumbnail" src="'+href+'' +thumbnailUrl+ '"/></a>');
             })//iterate each data
         });//json
    });;//click
});//READY FUNC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {//READY FUNC

$(".albumName").click(function(){//click
     var albumid = this.id;
     $('#imageFrame').empty();
     $.post("includes/viewgallery.php",{albumId:albumid},function(data)  {//json
        console.log(data);  
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
           $.each(data, function(key, val) {//iterate each data

               var albumName = val.albumName;
               var photoId = val.photoId;
               var photoName = val.photoName;
               var photoUrl = val.photoUrl;
               var thumbId = val.thumbId;
               var thumbName = val.thumbName;
               var thumbnailUrl = val.thumbnailUrl;
               var href = "http://217.199.187.191/mandingaarts.co.uk";

               $('#imageFrame').append('<a href="'+href+'' +photoUrl+ '" target="#lightbox"><img class="thumbnail" src="'+href+'' +thumbnailUrl+ '"/></a>');
             })//iterate each data

         });//json

    });//click

});//READY FUNC
```

A sample of this working is in the snippet below:

```js
//$(function(){ ... }); is an alternative to document.Ready(...)
$(function(){
  $("#imageFrame li").on("click", function(){
    $("#imageFrame").empty();  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imageFrame">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You are a star, Thankyou, From the script you adjusted I can see I was on the right track, if I'm correct the fact you changed the div id was the difference

Comment: I added the `$("#imageFrame").empty();` prior to you going into your `each`.  You did not have the `empty` in your original sample. Regardless, glad it helped.  Cheers!

Comment: I did try it there, but as often happens having someone getting you to try it again can resolve the problem